# fixed-action-btn inside a collapsible body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I am trying to add a fixed-action-btn inside a collapsible body. But in html page it is appearing in bottom right corner of page always not inside the collapsible. How to keep btn inside the body?

https://codepen.io/rils/pen/qpOoeJ

```
<div style="padding-left: 500px" id="rView">

    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion" id="reg_view">
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header">IPC > PS xxxx </div>
            <div class="collapsible-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s1 tooltipped " data-position="bottom" data-delay="50"
                         data-tooltip="I am a tooltip">
                        <input id="first_name" type="text" value="00" class="validate">
                        <label for="first_name">31-21</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s1">
                        <input id="first_name" type="text" value="01" class="validate">
                        <label for="first_name">20-8</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s1">
                        <input id="first_name" type="text" value="10" class="validate">
                        <label for="first_name">7-0</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s4">
                        <input id="first_name" type="text" value="0x11002200" class="validate">
                        <label for="first_name">0x40023ff8</label>
                    </div>
                     <div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal click-to-toggle" style="position: absolute">
                        <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
                            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
                        </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1"><i
                                    class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="btn-floating blue"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>FIELD</th>
                        <th>DESC</th>
                        <th>RW</th>
                        <th>DEFAULT VALUE</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>0-7</td>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>RW</td>
                        <td>1 INTERFACE</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>8-21</td>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>RW</td>
                        <td>2 INTERFACE</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>22-31</td>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>RW</td>
                        <td>3 INTERFACE</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `position:fixed` will place the element outside the document flow ***relative 
  to the closest viewport***. By default, that would be `<body>`.
- `position:absolute` will place the element outside the document flow ***relative to the closest positioned ancestor***. That would be the closest ancestor with a set `position`, other than `static` (which is default).

In conclusion, give your `<button>` `position:absolute` and your `<ul>` `position:relative;`

Comment: Thanks! As it was collapsible, due to the button position it was opening automatically. After adding `click-to-toggle` collapsible isnot opening automatically.

Comment: Hey, But i wanted to add FAB in each of the li in collapsible. After fixing position as u mentioned, FAB is appearing on main ul's bottom right corner. How to achive on each collapsible body's (li) bottom right corner ?

Comment: I read your position:absolute once again. I set positon relative to another ancestor and  Now it got fixed. Thanks for giving the concept.